# Hosting alternatives to WordPress.com

Tags: hosting

I've been hosting my blog on WordPress.com for a few years now, but am starting to feel a bit constrained by some of the limitations. The most troublesome in priority order are inability to include JavaScript in my posts, the requirement to pay an ongoing fee for customized CSS, and inability to install my own WP plugins.

I've thought about self-hosting, but the last thing I need is another side project of managing the blogging software. It's tough enough finding time to keep posting new content on the blog. I'm not interested in installing upgrades, doing backups, etc.

Long story short, I am wondering if there is another Wordpress hosting provider out there that offers the benefits of the virtually maintenance free hosting of WordPress.com, but without the restriction on CSS and Javasscript.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at

- [page.ly](http://page.ly)
- [WP Engine](http://wpengine.com)

I'm sure there are plenty of others.

I'm specifically discounting hosts that provide 1-click installs because even they require some administration.

Comment: Maybe those services solve the javascript issue, but it's worth noting that even the least expensive hosting options cost $240 or $350 per annum for the respective sites, which is a lot more than the $30 per annum for CSS on wordpress.com. So if javascript weren't an issue for other StackExchangers, you might be better off sticking with wordpress.com.