# What can I expect when moving from a hosted (WordPress.com) blog to one hosted by Page.ly

Tags: import, customization, hosting

As I mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15755/hosting-alternatives-to-wordpress-com), I'm planning to moving my blog to a new hosting provider from WordPress.com. I think I've settled on Page.ly as the new home for it, and I was hoping to get the benefit of experience from any of you who have transitioned an existing blog specifically from **WordPress.com** to **page.ly**.

**Some examples of the potential issues I'm trying to ferret out:**

- Am I going to lose any WordPress.com specific features in the transition?
- Any new maintenance issues/headaches that weren't there on Wordpress.com?
- Any surprise "Upgrade" fees for things I'm used to getting for free?
- What information can I expect to lose in an export/import process (Site stats, dates on comments/posts/subscribed users/something else?)
- General tips, advice, whatever that you wish you knew before you did the move.

Comment: There is nothing specific about moving from wordpress.com to page.ly, they are a host in an ocean of competition saturated by marketing innuendo. Wondering if this should be flagged.

Comment: @Wyck Not sure why you'd flag it, but that is your prerogative. I'm just looking for a heads up on what to watch out for.

Comment: It's to specific to one particular company, make it more along the lines of "moving hosts in general" and can possibly turn it into a community wiki.

Comment: Okay, that's fine, but I need information about switching to that one specific company since that is what I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can expect to lose your site stats.
- You can expect your site to be harder to find.
- You can expect to have greater freedom in terms of customization and possible features.
- You can expect to have to upgrade your WordPress version periodically.
- You can expect less users commenting, as WordPress.com uses a social networking style bar that won't be on your normal WordPress blog.
- You can expect to pay money for a really good theme, if you so choose.

Comment: Are you sure about the upgrade requirement? Their marketing literature seems to indicate they do that automatically for you in the background without you needing to keep up with it.

Comment: Well, it's pretty simple - you just hit automatically upgrade on your dashboard when it comes up, wait for it, then go back to WordPress again.

Comment: page.ly performs upgrades to WordPress core automatically. Lucas, have you used page.ly?

Comment: "You can expect your site to be harder to find." Why do you say that?

Comment: A standalone wordpress install doesn't have the same social capabilities of wordpress.com